# regression on grouped series from different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have about ~20 pandas data frames each containing anywhere from 100 to 1000 series with about 20,000 records in each.   These were created by importing from 20 separate CSV files and joining each to a common time series based on a UNIX timestamp, which is then set as the index of each dataframe.  The original files looking something like:

```
CSV file 1                             CSV file 2                        
___________________________________    _______________________________
datetime,         FldA, FldB, FldC     datetime,          FldA, FldC, FldD
2010/6/15 12:00,   0.5,  1.5,  2.5     2010/6/15 12:00,   0.3,  1.9,  3.4
2010/6/15 12:30,   0.6,  1.5,  2.2     2010/6/15 13:00,   0.7,  1.6,  3.5
2010/6/15 13:00,   0.4,  1.7,  2.3     2010/6/15 13:30,   0.4,  1.7,  3.2
```

which when imported into pandas data frames and each joined to a common timestamp, with a day of year field added, so looking something like:

```
dataframe 1                           dataframe 2                       
________________________________      ______________________________
time,       DOY,  FldA, FldB, FldC    time,       DOY,  FldA, FldC, FldD
1276603200, 166,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5     1276603200, 166,  0.3,  1.9,  3.4
1276605000, 166,  0.6,  1.5,  2.2     1276606800, 166,  0.7,  1.6,  3.5
1276606800, 166,  0.4,  1.7,  2.3     1276606800, 166,  nan,  nan,  nan
1276608600, 166,  nan,  nan,  nan     1276608600, 166,  0.4,  1.7,  3.2
```

Given these dataframes, I would like to perform a groupby on DOY in each dataframe and perform a linear regression for selected (common) fields from each of the 20 dataframes for each data grouping - so essentially:

```
linregress(FldA(dataframe_1, DOY = 166), FldA(dataframe_2, DOY = 166))
```

I have found posts for doing this type of operation using series from the same dataframe but not for series from different dataframes with the same index.

I've tried joining all the dataframes together but my machine chokes on that.  Any suggestions on how to go about this operation.

Comment: It looks like this question might *really* be about how to concatenate your DataFrames into a single one, and not really much to do with the regression. Is that about right? i.e. if you had a single DataFrame, could you do what you need to do?

Comment: yes and no.  I dont want to concatenate the data frames - for memory reasons.  However, I can do this by constructing a separate data frame from the pair of series and the index but that requires extra steps.  I was wondering if it is possible to do this in a single line - because I have many comparisons to do.